# What am I doing wrong when trying to set the default value for this radio button form element?

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

```
$options = array(
    'yes' => t('Yes'),
    'no' => t('No'),
    'maybe' => t('Maybe'),
  );

  $form['infx2670selig_kangaroo_eating'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => 'Would you eat a kangaroo?',
    '#default_value' => t('No'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

I don't see what's going wrong. By default, none are selected.

Answer (score 6):

The `#default_value` is the `key` in the `$options` array. you want:

```
'#default_value' => 'no',
```

Comment: +1. Also, if you want to make it easier to hold these key/value combo, just pass your linear array to `drupal_map_assoc`. It will return an associative array with both key and value same so you can use the same.

Comment: In this case, it is not possible to use drupal_map_assoc(), since you don't want t('No') to be used as key of the array.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set default value that's you've chosen before submit the form or in multisteps form then

```
$kangaroo_eating = isset($form_state['infx2670selig_kangaroo_eating']) ? $form_state['infx2670selig_kangaroo_eating'] : ''; <br> 
  $form['infx2670selig_kangaroo_eating'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => 'Would you eat a kangaroo?',
    '#default_value' => t('No'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $kangaroo_eating,
  );
```